# Why use "has" directly with an object in these types of contexts?

Tags: difference, usage, understanding

[Source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wash-up)

> Some of the **oil has washed up** on a neighboring island.

The bold part of the above sentence seems odd to me. It appears like oil is doing the process of washing up. For eg, when we say:

> He has read it.

It means the person has done the process of reading. Oil not should take the auxiliary verb "has" because it cannot do "washing-up".

I think it should be written like:

> Some of the oil has **been** washed up on a neighboring island.
>
> Some of the oil has **got** washed up on a neighboring island.

Another example of the same kind:

> If the counter decrements in value, which of the following operations **will follow**?
>   {A MCQ question format}

I believe it should also be **will be followed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use of *wash* is perfectly correct and entirely unremarkable.

It’s quite common for English verbs exhibit different argument structures in different contexts—for example, there's one in your final example that you haven't noticed, *decrement*. Several verbs designating cooking processes  may be cast either as transitives, with the food as object, or as intransitives, with the food as subject:

> Jane is boiling eggs.
>   Eggs are boiling on the stove.

An inanimate entity which is ordinarily the object of a verb with a human subject may become the subject of the verb if the action is attributable to some quality of the object:

> The Harry Potter books sold millions.
>   This car steers very poorly.

Verbs of motion like *wash* in your example are especially susceptible to variation between what might be called ‘automotive’ and causative senses:

> Horses galloped across the plain.
>   The warriors galloped their mounts across the plain.

These variations are comparable to the very old process of varying vowels in the stem which gave rise to ModE pairs like *lie/lay*, *rise/raise*, and *sit/set*.

You will find several questions on ELL about these verbs and their uses on ELL, tagged [middle-voice](/questions/tagged/middle-voice); other names are ‘ergative’, ‘multivalent’ and ‘labile’

Comment: My example is a middle voice in present perfect tense?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Basically, yeah. But it isn't really a 'voice', in the sense that term is ordinarily used--it's not marked inflectionally or syntactically, but by a shift in the syntactic role of the argument *oil*.

Answer (score 1):

*Wash* is a verb that can have an implied reflexive meaning.

> Some of the oil has washed up on a neighboring island = Some of the oil has washed [itself] up on a neighboring island.

In other languages like Spanish a reflexive pronoun would be used but not in English.

Also, sometimes to be colorful, non-boring, or dramatic, writers will give human or animistic qualities to objects.  So while oil doesn't really have the capability to move on its own, a writer or speaker may temporarily pretend it has that ability to make text or speech interesting or emotionally impactful.

Comment: The same is true for the other example also?

Comment: *X follows Y* doesn't necessarily mean X is walking after Y, but it can also mean X appears after Y.  That's built into the meaning of *follow*.  You don't want to say *will be followed* because it sounds like you are trying to say *will be followed by* - and that won't work because *X follows Y* = *Y is followed by X*